Bad Text render at large scale (EVEE). Cycle is fine
This is a very large text, around 500 meter. In EVEE it does not render properly. Clip end is set to 8000 meter so it should not be the issue. I have tried some basic setting like resolution etc and have tried converting it to mesh. I have changed the fonts, have tried multiple extrude methods. the problem occurs when the camera is far away. the text render properly in cycles.



Clip End does not matter in itself. What matters is the range between Clip End and Clip Start. Try reducing this range, it should solve your issue. Clip End should be as close as possible, Clip Start as far as possible.

thanks you that the solution @Lutzi
